# DIV POP UP containing clickable images using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an image button which changes images with a click of a button . This is the following code

```
function changeImg(thisImg)
{

    var altImg = "http://ww1.prweb.com/prfiles/2011/10/12/8875514/star_white.jpg";

    var tmpImg = null;

    function changeImg(thisImg) {

      tmpImg = thisImg.src;

      thisImg.src = altImg;

      altImg = tmpImg;

    }
```

this is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pUbrv/ which I did previously for clickable images

```
<img alt="" src="http://www.gettyicons.com/free-icons/136/stars/png/256/star_gold_256.png" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImg(this)" />
```

Instead of just chnaging the image by click of a button , I want to pop up a div which contains clickable images after I click the image in the div , the image choud change . Can please anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple Javascript solution.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pUbrv/2/)**

HTML

```
<body>
<img alt="" src="http://www.gettyicons.com/free-icons/136/stars/png/256/star_gold_256.png" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="myfunction(this)" />
</body>
```

SCRIPT

```
var altImg = "http://ww1.prweb.com/prfiles/2011/10/12/8875514/star_white.jpg";
    var tmpImg = null;
  function changeImg(thisImg) {
      tmpImg = thisImg.src;
      thisImg.src = altImg;
      altImg = tmpImg;
    }
function myfunction(ele) {
    var pop=new myPop();
    pop.popOut(ele);
}
function myPop() { 
    this.square = null;
    this.overdiv = null;

    this.popOut = function(ele) {
         tmpImg = ele.src;

        //filter:alpha(opacity=25);-moz-opacity:.25;opacity:.25;
        this.overdiv = document.createElement("div");
        this.overdiv.className = "overdiv";

        this.square = document.createElement("div");
        this.square.className = "square";
        this.square.Code = this;
        var msg = document.createElement("div");
        msg.className = "msg";
        msg.innerHTML = '<img alt="" src="'+altImg+'" id="imgClickAndChange" />';
        altImg = tmpImg;
        this.square.appendChild(msg);
        var closebtn = document.createElement("button");
        closebtn.onclick = function() {
            this.parentNode.Code.popIn();
        }
        closebtn.innerHTML = "Close";
        this.square.appendChild(closebtn);

        document.body.appendChild(this.overdiv);
        document.body.appendChild(this.square);
    }
    this.popIn = function() {
        if (this.square != null) {
            document.body.removeChild(this.square);
            this.square = null;
        }
        if (this.overdiv != null) {
        document.body.removeChild(this.overdiv);
        this.overdiv = null;
        }

    }
}
```

CSS

```
 div.overdiv { filter: alpha(opacity=75);
                      -moz-opacity: .75;
                      opacity: .75;
                      background-color: #c0c0c0;
                      position: absolute;
                      top: 0px;
                      left: 0px;
                      width: 100%; height: 100%; }

        div.square { position: absolute;
                     top: 200px;
                     left: 200px;
                     background-color: Menu;
                     border: #f9f9f9;
                     height: 200px;
                     width: 300px; }
        div.square div.msg { color: #3e6bc2;
                             font-size: 15px;
                             padding: 15px; }
```

Comment: sir, can I add multiple images inside the div and chnage the main image similar to smiley feature in gmail and whatsapp?

Answer (score -1):

Pollisbly the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated) dialog can help you.

Since the changing of images you have already implemented, you just need to put the images in the dialog.

Also you may like the **modal** functionality of the dialog.

**Edit**

If you don't want to use jQuery UI, then here is what you can do:

Create a new `div`.

Initially make it hidden or set its `display` property to `none`.

When user clicks on the image, make this div visible.

Set its position to `absolute` and set its `left` and `top` corrdinates as you want.

Add the image this `div`,

and finally add the event handler to this div for changing the images.

Comment: but I want a solution in javascript only cos I am working on javascript. Is it not possible in Javascript?

Comment: JQuery is written in JavaScript. But if you want do without the help of any library, it will be little painfull. But you can always do it.

Comment: can you please help me out with this without using jquery?

Comment: See my edited answer for the steps you may need to follow to do this.